# Openstack trove database instance status=error after creating a new instance

Tags: mysql, database, openstack

Recently I installed openstack trove using the automated script (devstack). After it is installed successfully and creating some user and projects, I manged to create a database instance and database inside it. unfortunately every database instance that I am going to build (via command line or horizon dashboard) trove gave me error status. Therefore when I tried to create database inside each of created database instance I stock with database instance is not ready.
I did some google and some people mentioned that I should check nova-compute.log, but unfortunately I did not find this log file. Would you please guide me?

Regards.

Comment: compute log is under - /var/log/nova/compute.log in my Redhat instance

Comment: unfortunately in mine it is not there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running devstack it creates a screen session for all the services and it contains the logs. Try running "screen -x" to attach to the screen session and you can view the logs from there. Each window within the screen session is a separate service running.

If you had an issue creating an instance from trove it maybe because the image you are using is not setup correctly for trove because it needs the trove guest agent installed and a configuration for the guest agent baked in the image.

We have a repo that uses devstack to create a development trove installation that might be of use to test things out. This readme should help getting you started.

https://github.com/openstack/trove-integration/blob/master/README.md